# directive with bindToController can't get data from child directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm tring to write a directive that builds an object from its child directive's input and pushes it
to an array provided as a parameter. Something like:

```html
<aggregate-input on="SiteContent.data.objList">
    <p aggregate-question>Question text</p>
    <input aggregate-answer ng-model="answer" type="text" />
</aggregate-input>
<aggregate-input on="SiteContent.data.objList">
    <p aggregate-question>Question text 2</p>
    <input aggregate-answer ng-model="answer" type="text" />
</aggregate-input>
```

I'm looking to collect the data like:

```js
SiteContent.data.objList === [
    {question: 'Quesion text', answer: 'user input'},
    {question: 'Quesion text 2', answer: 'user input 2'},
];
```

Here's the [plunker with the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ok2XI09Tw0IwCm9F7pYZ?p=preview).

- update 1: @jrsala included scope and bindToController syntax changes

I'm having trouble figuring out the way these directives should communicate. I'm expecting the `input`
object defined in the link will be isolated in the scope of each directive and pushed to the `on` object
provided. The result is that the `input` object is shared among all instances, and only one object gets
ever pushed to the array.

I'm guessing the transcluded scope rules are confusing me, but I really don't see where. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue: your `aggregate-input` directive specifies an isolate scope with no bound properties but you still use an `on` attribute on the element with the directive on it:

```
<aggregate-input on="SiteContent.data.objList">
```

but in your JS,

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: aggregateInputController,
    controllerAs: 'Aggregate',
    bindToController: { on: '=' },
    /* */
}
```

whereas what you need is

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { on: '=' },
    controller: aggregateInputController,
    controllerAs: 'Aggregate',
    bindToController: true // BOOLEAN REQUIRED HERE, NO OBJECT
}
```

As per [the spec](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)'s paragraph on `bindToController`,

> When an isolate scope is used for a component (see above), and controllerAs is used, bindToController: true will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope. When the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings are already available.

Then you do not need to assign the `on` property to your controller, it's done for you by Angular (also I did not understand why you did `this.on = this.on || []`, the `this.on ||` part looks unnecessary to me).

I suppose you can apply that to the rest of the code and that should be a start. I'm going to look for more issues.

**edit:** Several more issues that I found:

- If the scope of `siteContent` is isolated then the `SiteContent` controller is not accessible when the directive is compiled and Angular silently fails (like always...) when evaluating `SiteContent.data.objList` to pass it to the child directives. I fixed that by removing `scope: {}` from its definition.
- It was necessary to move the functionality of `aggregateInputLink` over to `aggregateInputController` because, as usual, the child controllers execute before the link function, and since the `aggregateQuestion` directive makes the call `InputCtrl.changeValue('question', elem.text());` in its *controller*, the `scope.input` assigned to in the parent directive post-link function did not exist yet.

```js
function aggregateInputController($scope) {
    $scope.input = {};
    this.on.push($scope.input);

    this.changeValue = function changeValue(field, value) {
        $scope.input[field] = value;
    };
}
```

As a reminder: controllers are executed in a pre-order fashion and link functions in a post-order fashion during the traversal of the directive tree.

- Finally, after that, the `SiteContent` controller's data did not get rendered property since the collection used to iterate over in `ng-repeat` was erroneously `SiteContent.objList` instead of `SiteContent.data.objList`.

Link to final [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vHxgveITrPp77DnztlIY?p=preview)

Comment: you're right, I got that syntax from [an article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) but it seems it never made it. Although I've made several tests with the documented DDO form and nothing changes. Thanks.

Comment: `this.on = this.on || [];` was to initialize `this.on` to an empty list in case the parent controller hadn't initialized the property yet.

Comment: @jminuscula But the parent controller's prototype is nowhere up the child controller's prototype chain! Is it?

Comment: in this case I mean SiteContent, the parent directive's controller, which does initialize `data.objList` to `[]`. `this.on = this.on || []` is only there in case the directive is provided a _"on" container_ object that is undefined.

Comment: @jminuscula I added issues that I found

Comment: thanks, I totally missed the fact that the siteContent directive controller was not accessible since it had an isolate scope. Changing that made things much clearer. I'm now also providing a function rather than objList to attach the aggregated object, which makes the access to the parent scope property much clearer. I'll be saving your modified plunkr for future reference. Many thanks!

Comment: @jminuscula You're welcome. To be perfectly frank with you, I only answer questions about angular to relieve others of some of the pain of using it. I hate angular.